# What Heinrich Hertz did different than Faraday

Tags: radio, induction, electromagnetic

Now this wiki page says Heinrich Hertz is the person who found radio waves. And [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Hertz#Electromagnetic_research), it describes how the experiment has done. He basically made first antenna. But years ago, Faraday found [law of induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction).

And I think Hertz's experiment adds nothing to Faradays law of induction. To me, he basically repeat the test. Then my question is: is there anything special with radio waves? Why wiki says he is the first person who proved the electromagnetic waves which theorized by Maxwell. Didn't faraday make the same experiment long ago?

Comment: Is your shift key broken? You should use capitalization to make your question more readable.

Comment: You need to go read some more about the history of science.  The gap between Faraday and Hertz (In terms of what was understood.) is huge.   I mean, in between was Maxwell.. and several others!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Induction is only half the story of an EM wave. Induction is all about alternating magnetic fields and coils of wire. In other words it doesn't take account of the "E" part of the EM field - it only deals with the "M" part.

Magnetic induction into a remote coil to produce an induced voltage reduces with distance cubed. The voltage induced into an antenna by an EM wave reduces with distance (not squared or cubed). The jump from a magnetic type induction to an electromagnetic transmission is significant.

Comment: faraday changed magnetic field. but if magnetic field is changed a current should flow. is it possible chancing magnetic field but not create an electric flow?  in second parag. you are saying he just improved it, am i right?

Comment: @user3301042 in theory yes. In practice however, discoveries from that time were not necessarily about inventing something new, but about gaining a new understanding and appliying that understanding in a new way. As such, Faraday could theoretically have transmitted information over, say, a couple of meters at best using coupled inductors. Herz' discovery and the theory developed by him however made him realize that with EM wave, much larger distances could be spanned.

Comment: I am saying that the sum of E + M is bigger than the individual parts by a long way. E (or M) on its own cannot provide long distance communication because the received field strength reduces dramatically compared to E+M. This is so very much more than an "improvement" - it's like comparing walking with space travel (OK I exaggerate slightly!). Also, if a mag field changes a current doesn't necessarily flow but there will be an associated E field change.

Comment: @RJR I agree technically so thanks for that but, from what I know, I don't think Hertz realized the implications of what he was physically demonstrating.